# How to use Exists function in List<string>?

Tags: c#, list

My Code is here:

```
string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);
            List<string> NewLines = new List<string>();
            foreach (string Line in Lines)
            {
                string newLine = Line.Trim();
                if (!NewLines.Exists(newLine))
                    NewLines.Add(newLine);
```

`NewLines.Exists()` function make this error:

The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Exists(System.Predicate<string>)` has some invalid arguments

Comment: I really believe reading MSDN documentation should be enough to answer such kind of questions.........

Comment: Might I suggest using a `HashSet<string>` if you file is quite large?

Comment: The code would be far more readable if you camelCased all the variable names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to check whether that line already exist in the list, use [`Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (!NewLines.Contains(newLine))
      NewLines.Add(newLine);
```

The [`Exists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx) method is expecting a `Predicate<string>` which you can use as follows:

```
NewLines.Exists(x => x == newLine)
```

Comment: Mer30, NewLines.Contains is my need